# Does android log somewhere which app was started/running when?

Tags: android, logging, logcat

Does android somehow keep track of which apps are/were running and if so when it was in foreground or background, etc?

I already had a look at adb logcat, which gives a rather overwhelming amount of data and I'm not quite sure if I actually will be able to deduce what was started when, but that might be possible.

Seeing how that log disappears after a while and does not survive reboots, I was curious if I'm maybe there might other places where android keeps information about running apps. For instance a colleague mentioned that iOS running apps can usually be deduced from the automatic screenshots it takes for app switching.